# How to run a web application through embedded Tomcat using maven cargo plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am creating a simple Hello World web application using maven cargo plugin. When I do cargo:run, the embedded tomcat starts on the given port(8081) but when I give the url in the browser, it shows HTTP Status 404- Not Found.
This is the name of the project- Todo-list and I have index.html file in the webapps folder. I am navigating to this url on my browser- http://localhost:8081/Todo-list/index.html
Here is my plugin configuration in the pom.xml file.

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: try to access only `http://localhost:8081`, do you see a tomcat page? If yes you have a problem in your application deploy, maybe the name is not `Todo-list`, or the file index.html doesn't exist, or it is in another folder. If the tomcat page is not showing, Tomcat itself is not booting, look for the log files in it.

Comment: I have tried accessing only http://localhost:8081, but the tomcat page is not showing up. I am getting status 404- Not found. When I checked the logs folder in target>cargo>configurations>tomcat9x, there seems to be nothing in this folder. Where to look for the exact error?